# Hiding checkbox of LayerNode in GeoExt?

Tags: geoext

I would like to hide/remove the checkbox of a LayerNode, since I need to have it always on display.

Is there any sort of option to do this, or must I use the Ext object hierarchy to locate the checkbox object and remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it, not very elegant, but it is a single line of code:

`treeNode.getUI().checkbox.hidden = true;`

Where `treeNode` is an object of the type `GeoExt.tree.LayerNode`.